# What is your dev flow for React Native Android?

Tags: android, react-native

For the last few weeks I've been developing an app for Android using React Native, and overall the experience is pretty good, however I feel like I might be missing something. Does anyone have any pointers?

My flow is

- Start Android Studio
- Wait for build/sync
- Run app on physical device or AVD
- See the expected red screen
- Start the Metro server
- Now the app is running
- Run `pidcat com.myapp` to see device logs
- Make JS changes via VSCode
- Hit reload in Flipper (no hot-reloading?)
- Re-navigate to the screen I'm working on

So far it's all good other than the lack of hot-reloading.
However whenever I made a change to some Java code, I need to hit Rebuild in Android Studio, and this takes quite some time usually.

Is this all normal? Perhaps I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to start Android studio.
If using Flipper, start Flipper first.
Start metro server in one terminal
run `react-native run-android` in another terminal.
To reload type `r` in the terminal with metro server.

Changes to JS side should automatically reflect in the device. ( https://reactnative.dev/docs/fast-refresh )
With react-native you shouldn't be making big changes to the native side of the codes. If reloading doesn't reflect the changes to the native side. Then close the metro server and build again.

Comment: Aha that's useful, thanks!

I did however need to work with the native code for a certain functionality.